# Nested for loops when vectorizing functions

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe, vectorization

I have a function with three for-loops. The function works, but it horrendously slow. I'm able to vectorize one for-loop, but was wondering if I could integrate the other for loops into the vectorization, or if there's anything else I can do to improve the efficiency.

Here's the for loop:

```
def getscore(df,df_out):
    for bait in df.columns:
        for tech in df_out:
            df_out[tech] = pd.Series(index = df_out.index, data = [int(df.loc[cust_id,bait]) * int(df_pim.loc[bait,tech]) for cust_id in df_out.index])
```

The function's operation isn't critical, but I want to see if there's a way where I can eliminate the for loops and integrate them into the vectorized line. Basically I need the code to loops through `cust_id`, `bait`, and `tech`.

EDIT: XY Problem clarification

I have three dataframes - I'm taking the column and index of one value in df_out and replacing it with the product of two values from two other dataframes. I'm replacing the value at `df_out.loc[cust_id,tech]` with the product of `df.loc[cust_id,bait]` and `df_pim.loc[bait,tech]`. I need to iterate through every `cust_id`,`bait`, and `tech`.

Comment: Zip df.columns and df_out https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). *The function's operation isn't critical* ... I believe it is because depending on what it does you may not need any loops! Please provide fuller, actual background (i.e., *X* problem not just your attempted *Y* solution) with [MCVE]. This looks like you just need to merge/join both dfs and run a calculated column.

Comment: Added the problem at hand